# pivot table using embedded sql statement

Tags: sql-server

I have created a select query that pulls in my ledger data and groups it into a table format.

```
select 
    chart.Uf_Mgr_PL_Line,
    MONTH(ledger.trans_date) as trans_month,
    chart.description,
    sum(ledger.for_amount)
From 
    ledger
        inner join chart on ledger.acct=chart.acct
Where
    ledger.control_year = '2016' and chart.Uf_Mgr_PL_Line <> 0
Group by
    Uf_Mgr_PL_Line,
    MONTH(ledger.trans_date),
    chart.description
Order by 
    Uf_Mgr_PL_Line
```

This is the data:

```
PL_LINE trans_month description AMOUNT  
2       9             COGS        100  
2         7    COGS -50  
2         4 COGS    -25  
3         9 Sales Returns - Other   200  
3         6 Sales Returns - Other   155  
3         5 Sales Returns - Other   30  
4         7 Sales Discounts 32  
4         4 Sales Discounts 400  
4         8 Sales Discounts 15  
4         5 Sales Discounts 35  
5         5 Price Protection Allowance  410  
5         6 Price Protection Allowance  22  
5         9 Price Protection Allowance  32  
5         4 Price Protection Allowance  44  
7         9 COGS - RMA Processing   -5  
7        8  COGS - RMA Processing   78  
7        5  COGS - RMA Processing   2555
```

So I need to pivot this data so that it looks like this

```
    PL_Line   desc               4   5  6   7  8   9  10  11  12  1  2  3
      2        Cogs             -25        -50    100
      3     sales return-other      30  155       200
      4     sales disc          400 35      32  15
```

I have been trying to do a pivot query, but I think my problem is with the column header section

```
    select *
           From 
           (    select 
                   chart.Uf_Mgr_PL_Line,
                   MONTH(ledger.trans_date) as [trans_month],
                   chart.description,
                    ledger.for_amount
                 From 
                    ledger
                       inner join chart on ledger.acct=chart.acct
                 Where
                       ledger.control_year = '2016' and chart.Uf_Mgr_PL_Line <> 0
             )AS s
             Pivot
            (   sum(amount)
            for [trans_month] in (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3)
            )as pivot
```

Part of a problem is I am getting an error message in for statement in the in criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting square brackets around the values in the `IN` criteria:

```
for [trans_month] in ([4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[1],[2],[3])
```

---

EDIT:

To "hide the `NULLS`", use:

```
SELECT PL_Line,[description],ISNULL([4],0) AS [4],ISNULL([5], 0) AS [5], ...
```

To sort specially, use:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PL_Line = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, PL_Line
```

Comment: Thanks that fix the error and I found a couple of others and I have some results.

Comment: So, now the question is, can I:
1-specify for ordering of the first col, PL_Line,  it goes from 2-30 in the full data, what I would like to have it show up as is 30, 2-29
  
2-How do I hide the nulls? either with a 0 or a blank?

Comment: Thank you for the updates.  I am trying to adding them to the query, but I am not sure where to put the order by statement.  I either have it in the wrong spot or there is a problem with the syntax, I keep getting an error next to =.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT *` is wrong, you should specify the columns in outer select and number column should be in square brackets :

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(
        PL_LINE INT, trans_month INT, [description] VARCHAR(30), AMOUNT INT
)
INSERT INTO @myTable
VALUES
(2, 9, 'COGS', 100),
(2, 7, 'COGS', -50),
(2, 4, 'COGS', -25),
(3, 9, 'Sales Returns - Other', 200),
(3, 6, 'Sales Returns - Other', 155),
(3, 5, 'Sales Returns - Other', 30),
(4, 7, 'Sales Discounts', 32),
(4, 4, 'Sales Discounts', 400),
(4, 8, 'Sales Discounts', 15),
(4, 5, 'Sales Discounts', 35),
(5, 5, 'Price Protection Allowance', 410),
(5, 6, 'Price Protection Allowance', 22),
(5, 9, 'Price Protection Allowance', 32),
(5, 4, 'Price Protection Allowance', 44),
(7, 9, 'COGS - RMA Processing', -5),
(7, 8, 'COGS - RMA Processing', 78),
(7, 5, 'COGS - RMA Processing', 2555)

    SELECT PL_Line,[description],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[1],[2],[3] FROM
    (
    SELECT * FROM @myTable
    ) AS t
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(AMOUNT)
        FOR [trans_month] IN ([4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[1],[2],[3])
    ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Would I put at the first select statement what I want to call the header instead of 4?  Like 
     SELECT PL_Line,[description],[4] as '2016 Apr',[5] as '2016 May'...
But still reference the [4],[5]... in the pivot section?